# Wordpress: Recent posts on homepage outside of ForEach loop?

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach

I'm new to Wordpress and I can't get my head around displaying recent posts on the Homepage without being in a ForEach loop. I am creating a site which displays the recent posts on the Homepage in a block layout (see a screenshot of the static page: http://prntscr.com/etriud), except one of the blocks is intentionally larger than the others and is why a ForEach loop won't work.

Is there a way to display the most recent posts outside of the ForEach loop on the page? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can manually get it from posts array by index and place into your code

Comment: But I prefer to use foreach loop just add some codition to drow with your logic

Comment: You retrieve back an array. How you process it is up to you. Loop through with condition checks or pick individuals by specifying array index like what's mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code, it's hard to be specific. If you know that you want to display the first image differently than the rest, you can still use the `foreach` construct.

```
$posts = array();
$i=0; // start the counter at zero
foreach ($posts as $post) {
    $i++; // increment the counter on each loop...
    if ($i == 1) {
        // do something different with the first post..
    } else {
        // do your normal stuff...
    }
}
```